# Tensor product of modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a polynomial ring over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $R_1=R/I$ for some ideal $I \subset R$. Let $M_1, M_2$ be $R_1$-modules. So, they are $R$-modules as well. Is it true that $M_1 \otimes_{R_1} M_2 \cong M_1 \otimes_{R} M_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can argue, vaguely, that $M_1 \otimes_R M_2$ "only depends on the action of $R$", and this is defined through its quotient $R/I$.  More precisely, $M_1 \otimes_R M_2$ is the quotient of the abelian group tensor product $M_1 \otimes M_2$ by the module generated by all relations $rm_1 \otimes m_2 - m_1 \otimes rm_2$, for $r \in R$ and $m_i \in M_i$.  And if $\bar{r}$ is the image of $r$ in $R/I$, these relations are the same as the one $\bar{r} m_1 \otimes m_2 - m_1 \otimes \bar{r} m_2$ for $M_1 \otimes_{R_1} M_2$.